# Get transaction's block number in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

The GET Endpoints for transactions only return the transactionId but I would like to get the block number too.

Is it possible to get a transaction's block number using the Hyperledger Composer REST API?. Any other workarounds involving other tools are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the Composer REST API.

However it should be possible using the Composer Javascript API - using the getNativeAPI() method from the BusinessNetworkConnection class.  This calls through to the Fabric SDK and queryTransaction() method of the channel class provides block information. Alternatively queryInfo() method will provide the block height.

The Composer API doc can be found here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/api-doc-index

and the Fabric SDK here:
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html

Note that the getNativeAPI() function available in the Composer Transaction Processor only exposes the chaincodeStub class in the Fabric SDK and so can't find Block information, which is why this is not possible in the REST API.

The Blockchain Explorer, has a REST API which exposes block information, however it is another component to configure and manage.